# Why can't I paste Chinese characters to Word?

Tags: ms-office

I have a strange problem with Word, every time I paste Chinese characters into Word, it looks like this:

[image]

However, I have no problem pasting Chinese characters to Pages(both 09 and 13 versions are OK), what should I do?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Do you mean Pages 09 and 13?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, question edited.

Comment: Which version of Office: 2008? 2011? What OS X Version?

Comment: Try switching to another Chinese font.  Normally Mac apps will automatically draw necessary characters from any font that has them, but Word will not, you have to have exactly the right one selected.  A major defect of the product.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install some fonts in order to make Word able to display those characters. This is a common problem with Asian languages - for example it is almost impossible to get Excel to show Thai fonts, although if you install Thai fonts on the system, Word will use them.

You also did not specify which version of MS Office you are running - older versions were even worse than recent versions.